# C# WPF MVVM ItemSource not attaching list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, itemssource

I have a list of  `Roles` that I want to have selectable in a `DataGrid` cell `ComboBox`.

I have the `ObservableCollection` `Roles` for the `ComboBox` being populated in the ViewModel.

For some reason, nothing shows up in the `ComboBox` though. What's the proper way of attaching this collection of objects?

Any comments or suggestions would be helpful.

**PersonModel:**

```
public int SelectedRole { get; set; }
```

**RoleModel:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public int Role { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public string RoleInfo 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return $"{Role} - {Description}";
    }  
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private ObservableCollection<PersonModel> _people;
public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> People
{
    get { return _people; }
    set
    {
        _people = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => People);
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<RoleModel> _roles;
public ObservableCollection<RoleModel> Roles
{
    get
    {
        return _roles;
    }
    set 
    {
        _roles = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Roles);
    }
}

public PersonViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IWindowManager windowmanager)
{
    _events = events;
    _windowManager = windowmanager;

    sql = "SELECT * FROM People";
    People = SqliteConnector.LoadData<PersonModel>(sql, new Dictionary<string, object>());
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Roles";
    Roles = SqliteConnector.LoadData<PersonModel>(sql, new Dictionary<string, object>());
}
```

**View:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          CanUserReorderColumns="True"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          AlternatingRowBackground="#dfdfdf"
          cm:Message.Attach="[Event RowEditEnding] = [Action SaveOrUpdate()]">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Role}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="RoleInfo"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Roles}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedRole, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedValuePath="Role" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataContext of the "row" elements of the DataGrid is the corresponding item of the ItemsSource collection, i.e. a PersonModel instance - which does of course not have a `Roles` property. You should have observed a corresponding data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio.

In order to bind to the Roles property of the parent view model, use an expression like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Roles,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```

The SelectedValue Binding could simply be like shown below, because `PropertyChanged` is already the default `UpdateSourceTrigger` for that property.

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedRole}"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program, check the output window to see exactly what kind of error is coming up for this control when it loads.  This will give you a better idea of the exception type being thrown.  My guess is that the ItemsSource of the ComboBox is looking for the ObservableCollection Roles in your Person Model, and is throwing an exception since Roles is in only in your ViewModel.  Try moving this collection to the Person Model and assign it's initial value via the Person Model constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind. I didn't seem to see any messages about that. Perhaps I'm using the output window incorrectly.

Comment: @Corey you would observe those messages when you run the debug version of your application in the debugger of Visual Studio: Debug -> Start Debugging or F5.